# LUKS and loop device

Tags: encryption, luks, cryptsetup

I read a lot of tutorials about LUKS/dm-crypt/cryptsetup, in particular about how to create an encrypted file container.

First step is to create the file with `dd`.

Then some tutorials map the file to `/dev/loop0` and format the loop device, other tutorials format directly the file without mapping it in a loop device.

My question: Is it necessary the loop device step? What is the difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't manage the loop device yourself, `cryptsetup` will automatically set up a loop device and close it when it is no longer needed. So there is no difference between the two; `cryptsetup` always works on the loop device. See `man cryptsetup`:

> NOTES ON LOOPBACK DEVICE USE
>
> Cryptsetup  is usually used directly on a block device (disk partition or LVM volume). However, if the device argument is
>   a file, cryptsetup tries to allocate a loopback device and map it into this file. This mode requires Linux kernel  2.6.25
>   or  more  recent  which supports the loop autoclear flag (loop device is cleared on last close automatically). Of course,
>   you can always map a file to a loop-device manually. See the cryptsetup FAQ for an example.
>
> When device mapping is active, you can see the loop backing file in the status command output. Also see losetup(8).

Answer (score 9):

You can use `dd` or `fallocate` (or `head` or a few other tools) to create a file to act as your container. Then as Vincent Yu stated `cryptsetup` can handle the loop setup/teardown for you.

```
fallocate -l 100M mypath/filecontainer
sudo losetup # Debug for demonstration, not necessary in a real script
sudo cryptsetup -y luksFormat mypath/filecontainer
sudo losetup # Debug for demonstration, not necessary in a real script
sudo cryptsetup luksOpen mypath/filecontainer filecontainer
sudo losetup # Debug for demonstration, not necessary in a real script
sudo mkfs -t ext4 /dev/mapper/filecontainer
sync
sudo cryptsetup luksClose filecontainer
sudo losetup # Debug for demonstration, not necessary in a real script
```

In the debug `sudo losetup` output, note the `AUTOCLEAR = 1` for the `filecontainer` entry. You *could* instead go crazy with `loopdev=$(sudo losetup -f); mount -o loop <etc>`, but letting `cryptsetup` handle it is **WAY** nicer.

The key is you want to make sure you FIRST use `cryptsetup luksOpen containerfile mappedname` to have it mounted to `/dev/mapper/mappedname` by default (you can give it a full path starting with `/` and it will mount there instead I believe, and THEN format the `/dev/mapper/mappedname` target and makes sure you are NOT touching the `filecontainer` directly, otherwise you are bypassing the encryption engine and just creating an unencrypted loopback file.